# How to remove previous application after upgrade?

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, wix-extension

I made a web application upgrade which is perfectly upgrading the app as well as registry and IIS entry. But after upgrade in registry it is replacing previous version(in IIS also). But in 'Program and features' section it showing both app version. What is happening here? What I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there registry entries are merely overwritten. Please check if the upgrade is successful. An installation log will clear this out.